# Conversion with LLVM

Tags: llvm, llvm-clang, llvm-ir, llvm-3.0

I was working on some project to convert a C+ACSL language into another language by converting first into LLVM IR and then convert it into another language. I cannot tell about that because it is related to a group of some people who do not want to disclose it, so we will not talk about it, but it is very close to C. I have completed the work till LLVM IR and also have written to convert it back, with the help of CBackend, but I really don't know how to use it, means how should I run that into my LLVM IR. Is there a command in LLVM for doing it, or something which can help me.

**UPDATE 1**
My input is LLVM IR and ouput is going to be a C like code, not C as it will be following syntax different from C.

Comment: The question is unclear. Can you specify in full detail what you want to run - what your inputs are and what the expected output is. The more detailed your question, the better chance you have of getting a good answer quickly

Comment: So, did you try LLVM 3.0 with the C backend? Did it work? What didn't work? What different do you need? Do you expect a full custom solution provided in a SO answer? If not, what *do* you need?

Comment: @Eli I tried C backend and it works, but it has lots of other issue like extra usage of unwanted variable. But it fine, what I need is the keywords use is going to be different as in our LLVM IR there a precondition `requires` written as a block name pre and there is a break conditional statement which should be written as `requires (condition)` in my output language. This is one of the change I needed. According to my need I have written the backend but now I want to know how to use it? how to check its correctness ?

Comment: @EliBendersky Is it possible?

Comment: Arpit: sorry but I still don't understand what you want. I will try to answer your question when you find a comprehensible way to ask it.